# multiple rails applications on same host name with different folders

Tags: apache2, webserver, amazon-ec2, rails

When i ssh to amazon ec2, then

```
pwd
/home/ubuntu


ls
app_1 app_2 app_3 app_4
```

Considering i have mapped my ec2-122**  address to some apps.site1.com

How can i have multiple rails applications running like if i access,

```
apps.site1.com/app_1 apps.site1.com/app_2 apps.site1.com/app_3
```

each of the application should be loaded.

One of my friends told he has implemented it for apache+php application, where various index.php files are
present and each folder structure is independently available as separate running application.

How can i implement this for rails applications,

Comment: Try asking this on [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issued using apache + passenger, passenger comes with suburi where using symlink and some changes in the apache.conf for the virtual hosts, same domain name can be used to run multiple application. [Documentation for reference](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#RailsBaseURI)